# Solving Permission denied problem

Tags: installation, command-line

When I try to install GIST program these words appear:

> Permission denied

So what does this mean and what can I do to solve this problem?

```
marwa@marwa-Vostro-1540:~$ cd Desktop/GIST_1.0/
marwa@marwa-Vostro-1540:~/Desktop/GIST_1.0$ ./GIST
bash: ./GIST: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

Permission denied when trying to run a file in the current directory usually means you don't have the execute permission for the file. Possibly, it's missing the executable bit, which you can add with the `chmod` command.

```
chmod +x ./GIST
```